# Where does the money gem get its formatting rules from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, currency

I'm using the money gem (Through rails-money) in my app, and currently it formats some currencies correct, but I noticed that Norwegian Krone (NOK) is formatted wrong. E.g.:

```
1.9.3-p327 :022 > Money.new(123400, "DKK").format
 => "1.234,00 kr" 
1.9.3-p327 :023 > Money.new(123400, "SEK").format
 => "1 234,00 kr" 
1.9.3-p327 :024 > Money.new(123400, "NOK").format
 => "kr1.234,00"
```

I would have expected NOK to be formatted the same way as DKK. What stumbles me in particular, is that I have not done any custom configuration for se and da (The locales corresponding to DKK and SEK), so not only don't I know why NOK comes out wrong, but I'm also not clear as to why SEK and DKK *does*.

Bonus: Why is the Swedish Krone formatted with a space for thousand-separator, when the Norwegian + Danish use a dot? (Both styles are btw. valid in all three languages ...)

Comment: I think this would be a question for the maintainer.

Comment: This is hardcoded in the gem: https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/blob/master/config/currency_iso.json - notice "nok" has "symbol_first" set to true. If this is incorrect, this should be filed as an issue on that project.

Comment: @DylanMarkow Spot on. Not sure how I managed to miss that. Could you make an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol-first part is hardcoded in the gem's configuration. Notice "nok" has `"symbol_first"` set to `true`.

If this is incorrect, this should be filed as an issue on that project.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a better answer

you should correct your model file and it will automatically fix it when displaying the format output

```
monetize :price_cents, with_model_currency: :price_currency
```